# Keep getting Array to string conversion notice, but code works fine

Tags: php

I have the following script to delete selected items from a table.

```
<?php 
    class deleteNews extends Generic 
    {
        private $error;
        private $news_id_delete;

        function __construct() 
        {
            if (empty($_POST['deleteCheck'])) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <strong>Erro!</strong> Nenhuma notícia foi selecionada! </div>';
            }

            if(isset($_POST['deleteCheck'])) {
                $this->news_id_delete = parent::secure($_POST['deleteCheck']);

                $params = array(
                    ':news_id_delete'       => $this->news_id_delete,
                );

                foreach($this->news_id_delete as $delete) {
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM `login_news` WHERE `news_id` = $delete;";
                    parent::query($sql, $params);
                }

                echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <strong>Sucesso!</strong> Sua notícia foi publicada! </div>';

           }
       }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['deleteBtn'])) {   
        $addUser = new deleteNews();                
    }    
?>
```

It works fine, the problem is that each time it executes, it returns the following Notice:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

How can I get rid of this notice?

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `$params` from

```
parent::query($sql, $params);
```

as I think your query is complete and doesn't need any extra params to be inserted in sql statement as id to be deleted is already passed in the query.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `login_news` WHERE `news_id` = $delete;"
```

Also `$params` is an array of arrays which is why you get this error from query function

Comment: Thanks!! It worked, I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.